# Java, array return

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm new at Java. I'm studying through Programming Hub app. When i read HeapSort code i find out that method fnSortHeap not return array but main method still can print out it. From informations that i found in main method must be smt like that:

> int arr2[];
>
> arr2 = fnSortHeap(arr, i - 1);

and in fnSortHeap method must

> return array;

```
class HeapSort
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int i;
        int arr[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 2};

        System.out.println("\nUnsorted Array\n---------------");

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }

        for (i = arr.length; i > 1; i--)
        {
            fnSortHeap(arr, i - 1);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nSorted array\n---------------");

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" " + arr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void fnSortHeap(int array[], int arr_ubound)
    {
        int i, o;
        int lChild, rChild, mChild, root, temp;

        root = (arr_ubound - 1) / 2;

        for (o = root; o >= 0; o--)
        {
            for (i = root; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                lChild = (2 * i) + 1;
                rChild = (2 * i) + 2;

                if ((lChild <= arr_ubound) && (rChild <= arr_ubound))
                {
                    if (array[rChild] >= array[lChild])
                        mChild = rChild;
                    else
                        mChild = lChild;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rChild > arr_ubound)
                        mChild = lChild;
                    else
                        mChild = rChild;
                }

                if (array[i] < array[mChild])
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[mChild];
                    array[mChild] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        temp = array[0];
        array[0] = array[arr_ubound];
        array[arr_ubound] = temp;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `fnSortHeap` method processes directly using the given `arr` the parameter. In fact, your `arr` has been changed every time the method called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is pass-by-value. please refer [java pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

I think your question is how the `main` method able to print sorted array when the method `fnSortHeap`is actually not returning anything.

If this is the question, then the answer is in the above link.
Anyways you are passing the array input and the method `fnSortHeap` is sorting the array the same array (not creating any duplicate), and the Main method is printing the same array.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! Didn't know about that. My first language was C